# mongodb credentials during openshift deployment via github

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github, mongoose, openshift

I want to use openshift to host my nodejs and mongodb app.
my mongodb are hosting on mongo atlas.

However openshift requires me to upload my application on github for deployment.
My question is how can I store my username and credentials of mongodb in this scenario. Clearly, I cannot just push the password on github and make it public.

my connection statement is

**Server.js**

```
var conString = "mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-e2zhz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-e2zhz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-e2zhz.mongodb.net:27017/chat?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin"
//var conString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mylearning";
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

mongoose.Promise = Promise

var Chats = mongoose.model("Chats", {
    name: String,
    chat: String
})

mongoose.connect(conString, { useMongoClient: true }, (err) => {
    console.log("Database connection", err)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use secrets. Documentation can be found at:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/secrets.html

Also check out 'Configuration and Secrets' chapter of 'Deploying to OpenShift' book at:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/deploying-to-openshift.html

The book is a free download.

You also don't have to have your code up up GitHub. You can use a binary input build. This is also covered in that book.

Comment: So after I created the YAML file, how should I modify my code respectively?

Comment: If you are going to create a YAML file and mount it, then you would need to modify your Node.JS code to read the YAML file from where you mounted it in the container, to get the credentials. If you had just created simple key/value secret and passed the values as environment variables sourced from the secret, reading that environment variable in the Node.JS code is probably easier.